# how to dynamically pass headers while making post request in django?

Tags: django

Right now I'm harcoding the token in headers and it works fine but i don't want to harcode it . I want to pass it while making post request in postman. So how to do that . Thanks in advance.

```
def addtocart(request):
    payload = request.data
    headers = {"content-type":"application/json", "token": "tk_ju9fdm8e", "source":"android"}
    response = requests.post('http://api/cart/update/v2', 
    data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

**UPDATED** **ANSWER** **:**

```
def addtocart(request):
     payload = request.data.copy()
     token = request.META.get('HTTP_TOKEN')
     headers = {"content-type":"application/json", "token": token, "source":"android"}
     response = requests.post('http://api/cart/update/v2', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
     return HttpResponse(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the `request.data` and insert in the `headers` dictionary.

```
def addtocart(request):
    token = request.META.get("token", None)  # if django>= 2.2 , you can use request.headers.get("token", None)
    headers = {"content-type":"application/json", "token": token, "source":"android"}
    response = requests.post('http://api/cart/update/v2', 
    data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192366/discussion-on-answer-by-aman-garg-how-to-dynamically-pass-headers-while-making-p).